# Vertx : Post data from html to Java

Tags: vert.x

I tried to send HTML form data to a Java Vertx Verticle but I get `null` as value.

Here is my code:

```
public void start(Future<Void> startFuture) throws Exception {
  Router router = Router.router(vertx);

  router.route("/html/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("html/"));
  router.route("/html/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("web/html"));
  router.route("/js/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("web/js"));
  router.route("/css/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("web/css"));
  router.route("/fonts/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("web/fonts"));

  Route route = router.route(HttpMethod.POST, "/crypt/testForm/");
  route.handler(routingContext -> {
    String productType = routingContext.request().getParam("test");
    System.out.println(productType);
  });

  vertx.createHttpServer()
    .requestHandler(router::accept)
    .listen(8085, "localhost", res -> {                    
      if (res.succeeded()) {
        startFuture.complete();    
      } else {
        startFuture.fail(res.cause());
      }
  });
}
```

And for my html file:

```
<form action="/crypt/testForm" method="post">
  <input type ="text" id="test" name ="test"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Regards.

Comment: There is a [simple example](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/web-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/web/form/Server.java) with a similar use case like yours. Perhaps this helps.

Comment: Thank you @alexvetter I forget to add router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());

Comment: You should consider adding an answer and mark it as the right answer to your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my solution, maybe it help,

```
      public void start() throws Exception {

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);  
    router.route("/html/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("html/"));    
    router.route("/html/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("web/html"));
    router.route("/js/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("web/js"));
    router.route("/css/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("web/css"));
    router.route("/fonts/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setWebRoot("web/fonts"));
    router.route("/crypt/test").handler(BodyHandler.create());
    router.post("/crypt/test").handler(ctx -> {
          ctx.response().putHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
          JsonArray js = new JsonArray();
          js.add(1);
          js.add(5);
          js.add(3);
          ctx.response().end(js.toString());
    });

    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8085);
  }
```